# Conditionally select column values sql

Tags: mysql

I've got an SQL table, homes, like this:

```sql
+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| id                     | home_one          | home_two          | test_val            |
+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| q6KPfv2bsnZTEdiK6McPn4 | 4214              | 1234  (*)         | 8                   |
| kTEHH6QA9wGGSnFDENeWHk | 6431              | 0251              | 5                   |
| fjLrUzp16vKaDWYMHoyvKQ | 1234  (*)         | 5381              | 8                   |
| hn89YvsayDWEYziv4jZBnR | 8241              | 1682              | 4                   |
| wK5QdX54A2z6uH7SKkHiao | 1234  (*)         | 9375              | 8                   |
+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

I'd like to filter on a condition such as

```sql
SELECT home_one, home_two FROM HOMES
WHERE test_val = 8
```

although I don't really want to get both home_one and home_two, but I only want to get either home_one, or home_two, depending on which one *does not equal* '1234'.

So my idea output would be something like:

```sql
+---------+
| results |
+---------+
|  4214   |
|  5381   |
|  9375   |
+---------+
```

I realize this could be done in the server logic instead, but I figure if there's a way to do this in SQL, that'd be nice, since the less server logic necessary, the less strain there will be on the server.

If there's some sort of command like this that can conditionally choose which column value to take for each row that would be what I'm looking for!

For reference, too, something like this is what would be used to make the homes table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE homes(
    id character varying(24) NOT NULL,
    home_one character varying (24) NOT NULL,
    home_two character varying(24) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY id
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the logic you mentioned to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN home_one <> '1234' THEN home_one ELSE home_two END AS home
FROM HOMES
WHERE test_val = 8 AND
      (home_one = '1234' AND home_two <> '1234' OR
      home_one <> '1234' AND home_two = '1234');
```

Comment: <> is stands for not equal or !=